# Extracting specific interaction coefs from the same linear model in R

Tags: r, lm, glm, interaction

I'm interested in particular effects (or parameters) of a linear model. For example, taking the iris dataset, I would be interested in:

1. How `Sepal.Width` modulates the effect of **versicolor** and **virginica** (compared to the reference level **setosa**).
2. The linear relationship between `Sepal.Width` and `Sepal.Length` in each of the three levels of `species`.

The only way I found to do it is to fit two models, one with interaction and the other with nested interaction:

```
fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species * Sepal.Width, data=iris)
summary(fit)  # The two last lines

fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species / Sepal.Width, data=iris)
summary(fit)  # The three last lines
```

Nevertheless, fitting twice the *same* model seems relatively inefficient (especially when fitting models that take a long time to compute).

Is there any way to obtain, from a single model, the equivalent of the two last lines of the first model and three last lines of the second model? thanks

Comment: Do you obtain the desired answer by doing `fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species * Sepal.Width + Species / Sepal.Width, data=irs)` ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this returns the exact same output as fit 1 (with only species * sepal.width)

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the *coefficient estimates* from the summary, then from a single model, the equivalent of the two last lines of the first model and three last lines of the second model can be obtained through addition. Let me explain.

In reality, both summaries are giving you the same information, just in different ways. For the first summary, here is my output:

```
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                     2.6390     0.5715   4.618 8.53e-06 ***
Speciesversicolor               0.9007     0.7988   1.128    0.261    
Speciesvirginica                1.2678     0.8162   1.553    0.123    
Sepal.Width                     0.6905     0.1657   4.166 5.31e-05 ***
Speciesversicolor:Sepal.Width   0.1746     0.2599   0.672    0.503    
Speciesvirginica:Sepal.Width    0.2110     0.2558   0.825    0.411
```

This is the result from the fit when **setosa** is dropped from the model. This automatically occurs in R because when you pass in a factor to a linear model, you only need `n-1` parts to describe it since the base-level part (in this case **setosa**) is entirely collinear with the other two factors.

In the second summary fit, this is what I see.

```
                              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                     2.6390     0.5715   4.618 8.53e-06 ***
Speciesversicolor               0.9007     0.7988   1.128    0.261    
Speciesvirginica                1.2678     0.8162   1.553    0.123    
Speciessetosa:Sepal.Width       0.6905     0.1657   4.166 5.31e-05 ***
Speciesversicolor:Sepal.Width   0.8651     0.2002   4.321 2.88e-05 ***
Speciesvirginica:Sepal.Width    0.9015     0.1948   4.628 8.16e-06 ***
```

In this model, despite being entirely collinear, the base-level **setosa** is kept in the model. Normally, if one were to keep an entirely collinear variable in a model, R would return an error because it would complain that it can't invert the matrix to find the best-fit for the desired formula (this is because the matrix is not full-rank).

But R is okay with the model because, well, it returned it successfully. This means the matrix was invertible because, despite having all three levels of the factor in the interaction terms, it was still a full-rank matrix. Using this knowledge, I thought that the information of whatever was "missing" from the second model was just baked into the first model.

And that's exactly what I saw. Look at the following equations, with the coefficient from model 1 on the left side of the equation, and the coefficient from model 2 on the right side of the equation.

```
Sepal.Width = Speciessetosa:Sepal.Width
Sepal.Width + Speciesversicolo:Sepal.Width = Speciesversicolor:Sepal.Width
Sepal.Width + Speciesvirginica:Sepal.Width = Speciesvirginica:Sepal.Width
```

Therefore, to obtain the *coefficient estimates* from the last two lines of the first model and the last three lines of the second model, just simply take the summary of the first model, and then perform the three equations I wrote above to obtain the "extra" information stored in the last three lines.

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation! Do you think it would be possible to do something similar to have the "significance" (the p value) of these reconstructed coefficients? Additionally, I reckon this solution would work for a frequentist model but not for a Bayesian model where, instead of having a point-estimate, you end up with a distribution. It seems complicated to simply "add" two posterior distributions together, but maybe I'm wrong. Anyway thanks, this helps already.

Comment: Yea, I was trying to figure out how to obtain the standard deviation, t-value, and p-values from the other coefficients but was having trouble since it's not immediately obvious how they can be obtained. It was not through simple multiplication or addition this time.

Actually, I was just thinking.The standard error and p-values can be obtained if you can re-invert the matrix. [This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/how-are-the-standard-errors-of-coefficients-calculated-in-a-regression/44841) reveals that if you were to modify the design matrix by addition,it could reveal

Comment: But going through all that trouble seems too complicated, and not sure if it will even work correctly. Anyway, at least you have a coefficient solution...